# How to select Mode of data that is text in google sheets with criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I'm trying to find the mode of a data set given a certain criteria of employee population.

I've run into two problems and have been able to solve one.

Problem one was that the mode wasn't a value so i had to figure out how to have it return a text result.

Now, my problem is getting it to return the mode for the appropriate demographic (female, male, or non-binary). Right now, the formula is returning the mode for the entire data set and i cannot figure out how to get it to return for only one gender.

I've tried:
=if(Data!C:C=B3, INDEX(Data!$B:$B,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(Data!$B:$B,Data!$B:$B)),COUNTIF(Data!$B:$B,Data!$B:$B),0)),"")

it returns the false value. I am just not sure how to get the criteria portion. Please help if you can!

Here's the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EHdL098jNEmtthDSirHR2byHxwkQWYwFP3f6X0G4uU/edit#gid=753302828

Comment: please update the sharing settings to Anyone with the link > Editor. Right now we cannot test any solution.

Comment: @z.. this is updated now for editing. thanks!

Comment: @z.. thank you for your help! what if the the data set is in columns O - AD? O is the rating and AD is the gender? When i update your formula to select Col1 .... where Col16 = .... i get an error that says "Index parameter 2 value is 2. Valid values are between 0 and 1 inclusive. I updated the data to reflect it more accurately. Sorry about that.

Comment: you have to update the range as well: B:C -> O:AD or B:C -> {O:O,AD:AD} with the same query.

Comment: @z..i'm so sorry but do you know how to add additional criteria? I am guessing it would be adding another query portion after? Trying to add another criteria of if promoted or not promoted. Would it be a nested query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=INDEX(QUERY(Data!B:C,"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col2='"&B3&"' group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc"),2,1)
```